# Trigger AWS Lambda by cloudwatch and insert record into RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I've created a lambda to listen to some of the tags of certain logs to extract the info. And the requirement is to insert these records into a DB, for which I'm using RDS. But as lambdas are stateless, every time I need to do a transaction, need to setup the DB connection. So In a situation where multiple records are received by the lambda in high frequency, is this arrangement going to throttle?

If that's the case, then should I use a queue to extract necessary info from the logs and then invoke the lambda?

Comment: If you make sure the connection is made outside the handler it will persist for subsequent executions. DNS resolution errors would be a more likely error since the improved networking for lambda. Make sure to retry DNS errors and exit the function if they persist

Answer (score 0):

The lambda concurrent execution limit is 1000 per region, which can be increased on request. This is quite a substantial number and should cater to a lot of requirements. Check what is your maximum concurrent execution requirements and compare whether they fit in the default limit.

[AWS Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

Comment: This limitation of lambda is well within the requirement. My only concern is, since the DB connection needs to establish upon each lambda invocation (which takes a certain amount of time), will it lead to some data loss. And if so, what's the recommended solutions.

Comment: You need to provision database according to your load requirement as well.

Comment: Where do you fear the loss will come from? CloudWatch will trigger a Lambda function. The Lambda function will communicate with the database. Are you worried that Lambda might fail to connect to the database if the database is too busy? If so, you could instead choose to send the messages to an Amazon SQS queue and then process the messages as a batch via a scheduled Lambda.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeah that's the worry. In case it's slow and takes time to initiate the connection, will I miss data. I think queue seems to be the best solution.